# Why Recursion + Memorization Gives TLE?

Tags: c++

Okay we know that the time complexities of Iterative and memoriztaion is same. but still on leetcode it gives TLE for this. Problem : https://leetcode.com/problems/partition-equal-subset-sum/
Also Im using Call by Reference but still.
Am i doing it wrong or missing something?

Code :

```
public:
    bool isPresent(vector<int>& a, const double& sum, int i, vector<vector<bool>> &dp) {
        int n = a.size();
        if(i == n) return false;
        
        if(sum < 0) return false;
        if(sum == 0) return true;
        
        if(dp[i][sum] == true) return true;
        
        if(isPresent(a, sum - a[i], i+1, dp) || isPresent(a, sum, i+1, dp))
            return dp[i][sum] = true;
        return dp[i][sum] = false;
    }
    bool canPartition(vector<int>& a) {
        
        int n = a.size();
        int s=0;
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++) {
            s += a[i];
        }
        double sum = ((double)s) / 2.0;
        vector<vector<bool>> dp(n+1, vector<bool> (sum+1, false));
        
        return isPresent(a, sum, 0, dp);
    }
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using your memo only when `dp[i][sum] == true`.
In other words, you are not using the memorized information that there won't be any solution for that parameter.

You will need (at least) 3-state memo table: "true", "false", and "not yet calculated".

Here is one example using another table `dpValid`:

```
public:
    bool isPresent(vector<int>& a, const double& sum, int i, vector<vector<bool>> &dp, vector<vector<bool>> &dpValid) {
        int n = a.size();
        if(i == n) return false;
        
        if(sum < 0) return false;
        if(sum == 0) return true;
        
        if(dpValid[i][sum] == true) return dp[i][sum];
        
        dpValid[i][sum] = true; // [i][sum] won't be visited in further recursion, so we can raise flag at here
        if(isPresent(a, sum - a[i], i+1, dp, dpValid) || isPresent(a, sum, i+1, dpValid))
            return dp[i][sum] = true;
        return dp[i][sum] = false;
    }
    bool canPartition(vector<int>& a) {
        
        int n = a.size();
        int s=0;
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++) {
            s += a[i];
        }
        double sum = ((double)s) / 2.0;
        vector<vector<bool>> dp(n+1, vector<bool> (sum+1, false));
        vector<vector<bool>> dpValid(n+1, vector<bool> (sum+1, false));
        
        return isPresent(a, sum, 0, dp, dpValid);
    }
};
```

Comment: Worked!!! but still iterative are faster lol Thanks